# Render React Components synchronously in order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mobx

I am creating a React app and using Mobx for state management. The code looks like this:

```
@observer
class ComponentX extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.renderC = this.props.renderC;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <ComponentA />
                </div>

                <ComponentB mousePosition={this.props.mouseCoordiantes}/>

                {this.props.renderC && <ComponentC/>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`<ComponentC/>` does some DOM manipulation that requires `<ComponentB/>` to render fully before it does its stuff. `ComponentX` is re-rendered continuously, causing child components to also re-render, when the user moves mouse, because `<ComponentB/>` uses those mouse coordinates as props. (`mouseCoordiantes` and `renderC` are Mobx `observables`, so whenever their value changes, the components using them re-render automatically). Depending on the mouse position,  `renderC` is set to `true` which causes `<ComponentC`/> to render.

However, when `renderC` is set to `true`, `<ComponentC/>` renders before `<ComponentB`/> has completed rendering to DOM. And so the desired outcome is not achieved. Why is this happening and how can I make sure that `<ComponentC/>` renders only after `<ComponentB/>` has rendered fully?

Comment: Make `C` a child of `B`

Comment: Use the life cycle methods to know when the componets are fully rendered, then send a prop to component C to apply its logic.

Comment: "<ComponentC/> does some DOM manipulation that requires <ComponentB/>..."  doesn't sound like good idea. Consider rethinking the way you decompose you app into components.

Comment: @MarkE: I tried that but it didn't work. I created an additional variable in the store and used it as an additional condition for rendering `ComponentC` by updating that variable to `true` via a method inside `ComponentB`'s `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` methods. But it did not make any difference.

Comment: @lux: How will that help?

Comment: It will help because you won't have to hack your hierarchy to NOT render it's children. Rather outsource that decision to B since it can decide when C is renderable.

Comment: @lux: If I put `componentC` inside `componentB`, how will `componentB` guarantee that `ComponentC` is rendered only after it has rendered itself first?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

```
class ComponentB {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({renderC: true});
  }

  render() {
     return <div>
        ...
        {this.state.renderC && <ComponentC />}
     </div>
  }
}

class ComponentX {

  render() {
    <ComponentB />
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work as it will go in an infinite loop of rendering `ComponentX` because as soon as `ComponentB` renders, it will cause `setState` on `ComponentX`, which will re-render `ComponentB` again and the whole process will repeat.

Comment: Think youre right. I updated my answer with another alternative